# Find same words in two text files

Tags: sorting, text, comm

I have two text files and each contains more than 50 000 lines. I need to find same words that are in both text files. I tried COMM command but I got answer that "file 2 is not in sorted order". I tried to sort file by command SORT but it doesn´t work. I´m working in Windows. It doesn´t have to be solved in command line. It can be solved in some program  or something else. Thank you for every idea.

Comment: tell a bit more about your text. one word per line? or CSV? or what? give some examples would be good

Comment: First text file contain one word with character #, & or * per line. And second file contain one word with number per line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort the files you will have to use some sort of external sort (like merge sort) so you have enough memory. As for another way you could go through the first file and find all the words and store them in a hashtable, then go through the second file and check for repeated words. If the words are actual words and not gibberish the second method will work and be easier. Since the files are so large you may not want to use a scripting language but it might work.

Comment: 50k lines is not large. if a line has normal length. it would be ok to process in memory.

Comment: whatever you say Kent, since he mentioned the number of lines in the file I thought it may have been an issue for him thats all

Answer (score 0):

If the words are not on their own line, then comm can not help you.

If you have a set of unix utilities handy, like Cygwin, (you mentioned comm, so you may have have others as well) you can do:

```
$ tr -cs "[:alpha:]" "\n" < firstFile | sort > firstFileWords
$ tr -cs "[:alpha:]" "\n" < secondFile | sort > secondFileWords
$ comm -12 firstFileWords secondFileWords > commonWords
```

The first two lines convert the words in each file in to a single word on each line, it also sorts the file.

If you're only interested in individual words, you can change `sort` to `sort -u` to make get the unique set.